# How to display controller's data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I cant display data on my view , i think i am doing something wrong with my controller but i dont understand.

my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Projects;
use Auth;


class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Projects $projects)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->projects = $projects;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Projects::get();
        $this->$projects;
        return view('welcome')->with('projects', '$projects');
    }
}
```

route:

```
Route::get('test', [
    'uses' => 'WelcomeController@index',
    'as' => 'welcome',

    ]);
```

view:

```
                <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Projects: </p>
                <p>Users:  </p>
                <h3>Project: {{ $project->title }} </h3>
```

what im getting: http://188.166.166.143/test

Comment: `<h3>Project: {{ $project->title }} </h3>` should be ` <h3>Project: {{ $projects->title }} </h3>` also what does `$this->$projects;`
 do ?

Comment: Also remove quotes around `projects` variable: `with('projects', '$projects')` => `with('projects', $projects)`

Comment: can you see any data with {{ $projects[0]->title }}

Comment: You got an array so use index for each time (loop) and for simply display first record use like  $projects[0]->title . hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Projects;
use Auth;


class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Projects::get();
        return view('welcome')->with('projects', $projects);
    }
}
```

And your view should be something like this as Komal said.

```
<table id="table-projects" class="table table-hover">
 <thead class="text-center">
   <tr>
     <th width="10%"><center>Project Name</center></th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    @foreach($projects as $project)
      <tr>
       <td>{{$project->title}}</td>
      <tr>
    @endforeach   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$projects = Projects::get();` will give the collection of projects.

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
   <h3>Project: {{ $project->title }} </h3>
@endforeach
```

this will give the title of each projects.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
  $projects = Projects::all();
  return view('welcome')->with('projects', '$projects');
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/test', 'WelcomeController@getIndex');
```

Your html

```
<table id="table-projects" class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="text-center">
    <tr>
      <th width="10%"><center>Project Name</center></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($projects as $project)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$project->title}}</td>
      <tr>
    @endforeach   
  </tbody>
</table>
```